# How do you make the expected object in an assertEquals method a pose (in a function, see code below) instead of an integer or double?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to code a Unit Test for a method translatePose (code below).

```
public TrcPose2D translatePose(double xOffset, double yOffset)
    {
        final String funcName = "translatePose";
        TrcPose2D newPose = clone();
        double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(newPose.angle);
        double cosAngle = Math.cos(angleRadians);
        double sinAngle = Math.sin(angleRadians);

        newPose.x += xOffset*cosAngle + yOffset*sinAngle;
        newPose.y += -xOffset*sinAngle + yOffset*cosAngle;

        if (debugEnabled)
        {
            dbgTrace.traceInfo(funcName, "xOffset=%.1f, yOffset=%.1f, Pose:%s, newPose:%s",
                    xOffset, yOffset, this, newPose);
        }

        return newPose;
    }   //translatePose
```

I wrote out a quick template, which looks like:

```
public class TrcPose2DTest {
    @Test
    public void testTranslatePose() {

        assertEquals(0.0, new TrcPose2D(0,0));
        assertEquals(4.46, new TrcPose2D(4,2).translatePose(4,2).x, 1e-9);
        assertEquals(3.58, new TrcPose2D(4,2).translatePose(4,2).y, 1e-9);
```

The problem is that assertEquals is trying to compare a double to a pose generated by the method translatePose. However, I am unsure of how to make the expected value a pose, like the way the actual value is. I thought about making a variable called TrcPose2DResult and setting that equal to a pose, but I am not sure exactly of how to implement this.

Comment: You clearly know how to instantiate TrcPose2D, so it's unclear to me what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is your first assertion:

```
assertEquals(0.0, new TrcPose2D(0,0));
```

As you are comparing the double 0.0 to a TrcPose2D object in that assert.

I would check the x and y values of that TrcPose2D object instead as you do in the other two assertions which are also a double value:

```
assertEquals(0.0, new TrcPose2D(0,0).x, 1e-9);
assertEquals(0.0, new TrcPose2D(0,0).y, 1e-9);
```

And leave the other two assertions as they are to test the `translatePose` method.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the values in assertEquals, I'm assuming that the `translatePose(4,2)` returns a `TrcPose2D` with `x = 4.46` and `y = 3.58`. This is equivalent with creating the object like this: `new TrcPose2D(4.46,3.58)` . Now to test the actual objects, you have first to override the `equals()` method in `TrcPose2D` for the `x` and `y` attributes:

```
public class TrcPose2D {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    //constructor

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TrcPose2D trcPose2D = (TrcPose2D) o;
        return Double.compare(trcPose2D.x, x) == 0 &&
                Double.compare(trcPose2D.y, y) == 0;
    }
}
```

Now that the equals method have been overridden, we can write our test like this:

```
public void testTranslatePose() {

    TrcPose2D expectedResult = new TrcPose2D(4.46, 3.58);
    TrcPose2D poseBeforeTranslate = new TrcPose2D(4, 2);
    TrcPose2D actualResult = poseBeforeTranslate.translatePose(4, 2);

    assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);

}
```

**EDIT** : we needed to override the equals() method because the `assertEquals()` behind the scenes is doing something like this :

```
if (expectedResult == actualResult)
        return true;
    return false;
```

And when we compare two **objects** with `==` the `.equals(Object o)` method is invoked. And in our case, to correctly compare our 2 poses, we needed to check if the current `x` value is equal to `o.x` value and same for `y`.